# How to calculate the password hash in /etc/shadow

Tags: password, hashsum, shadow

I have the following line in my `/etc/shadow` file (`SALT` and `HASHED_PASSWORD` are not real values for obvious reason). And I understand `$6` means SHA512 is used.

```
testuser:$6$SALT$HASHED_PASSWORD:19591:0:99999:7:::
```

I wonder how do I combine the `SALT` and my real password `PASSWD` as input for SHA512 to get the `HASHED_PASSWORD` value?

I tried to run `sha512sum` command and paste in `PASSWD`+`SALT` and `SALT`+`PASSWD` (without the `+` sign). But the result is nothing like the `HASHED_PASSWORD` stored in the file.

Comment: @DrizzleX The insight you may be missing is that the algorithm is not just salted SHA512, but rather a *series* of multiple sha512+salt hashing iterations (thousands of them), in order to make the hash "slower" (bad for the attacker, good for the defender)

Comment: @RoyceWilliams that makes sense.

Comment: The second insight needed is that output of `sha*sum` is usually hex but the crypt output is base64 (but _not_ the traditional base64!)